# Losing TCP packets in .NET but not in VB6

Tags: vb.net, tcp

I'm having some issue with my TCP Client in VB.NET 2010, I'm trying to send a string of about 300KB but only about 200KB are received on the other side.
The remote machine is in another building and the application is compiled in VB6.
My application is compiled in VB.NET 2010 and it works fine if I both ends runs an application compiled in VB.NET or both in VB6
But if the sender is a VB.NET application the packets are lost.

I even tried adding a 15seconds delay with the same results.

What can be happening?

```
Private Function SendReport(ByVal Msg As String, ByVal Host As String, ByVal Port As String) As String
        Try

            Using Tx As New TcpClient()
                Dim stream As NetworkStream = Nothing
                Dim CloseStream As Boolean = False
                Dim LingerMode As New LingerOption(True, 5)

                Dim MsgUTF8, MsgUnicode, MsgUTF32 As String

                'Msg = Msg & "*" & Chr(23)
                MsgUTF8 = Msg & "*" & Chr(23)
                '  MsgUTF32 = "UTF32 " & Msg & vbCrLf
                '  MsgUnicode = "Unicode" & Msg & vbCrLf
                ' String to store the response ASCII representation.
                Dim responseData As [String] = [String].Empty

                Tx.LingerState = LingerMode
                Tx.SendTimeout = 10000
                Tx.ReceiveTimeout = 10000
                Tx.NoDelay = True
                Tx.SendBufferSize = 512000

                Tx.Connect(Host, Port)

                ' Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
                ' Dim data As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Msg)
                Dim dataUTF8 As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(MsgUTF8)
                ' Dim dataUnicode As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(MsgUTF32)
                ' Dim dataUTF32 As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(MsgUnicode)

                ' Get a client stream for reading and writing.
                '  Stream stream = client.GetStream();
                stream = Tx.GetStream()
                CloseStream = True
                'stream.WriteTimeout = 100
                ' Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
                ' stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
                stream.Write(dataUTF8, 0, dataUTF8.Length)
                'stream.Write(dataUTF32, 0, dataUTF32.Length)
                ' stream.Write(dataUnicode, 0, dataUnicode.Length)

                '' Close everything.

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000)
                If CloseStream = True Then
                    stream.Close()
                End If

                Tx.Close()
                Return responseData
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            WriteRTBLog(ex.Message, Color.Red)
            WriteRTBLog(ex.StackTrace, Color.DarkRed)
            Return "Error"

        End Try

End Function
```

Comment: The odds that Encoding.UTF8 can work when the VB6 app is on the other end of the wire are excessively low.  You'll have to set the clock back to the previous century and use Encoding.Default instead.

Comment: May not be your problem, but I do this this code that is likely wrong: `MsgUTF8 = Msg & "*" & Chr(23)`. Strings in .Net are stored in UTF32, so there may be a character encoding issue causing problems for you.

Comment: @HansPassant The first encode that I use was ASCII but some characters above "z" are changed to "?". I will try with default encoding. Can be some trouble with the long of the string? Because the VB6 remote application always receive around 199KB and 200KB. I'm thinking in to send the data in smaller packets of 100KB.

Comment: The bug is in the receiver. You posted the code of the sender.

Comment: @usr Thanks, for answer me. Do you have performed a connection from .NET VB6 before and it works? The receiver code is from another enterprise, so I have no access to.